# I want to run MongoDB on OpenVZ, but crashes expected — what can I do about it?

Tags: openvz, mongodb, virtuozzo, outofmemoryerror

My Server is hosted on HostEurope, a virtual server

uname -a prompts

**Linux lvps176-28-21-237.dedicated.hosteurope.de 2.6.18-028stab095.1 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 20:15:15 MSD 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

They are running OpenVZ. According to the support of HostEurope, an up to date version of Virtuozzo, but reading the version history on OpenVZ, this version is old, frozen and won't be maintained any more. Who is right?

My actual problem is that I want to run a MongoDB, but I am confronted with this OpenVZ problem explained here:

[Crashes reported on OpenVZ](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1121)

So, what can I do? Is there any chance to solve this Out-Of-Memory issue in MongoDB on OpenVZ in this version or do I have to find an other hosting company?

Thanks!

Comment: When a host says something that's clearly false after a quick Googling, it's usually time to ditch the host.

Comment: I'd say your question is kinda strange. Obvious answers are "try first and see", "don't use OpenVZ", "don't use Mongo", "debug and patch it", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason here is that the hosting provider is running on RHEL/CentOS 5.x under the covers - those are "stuck" permanently on the 2.6.18 kernel branch you reported, to get to something more recent they would have to upgrade to RHEL/CentOS 6.x - so while they are correct that they are on the latest version of OpenVZ for their platform, the platform is what is lagging behind.

As [this comment](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$pushAll) explains, there just aren't really any good options to fix the underlying issues with OpenVZ on the older platforms.

So, either ask if they have more up to date hosts available (perhaps they are trialling 6.x on a limited basis), or yes, move elsewhere.